# Why NetStream#togglePause() do not work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, red5, netstream

I create a record audio application based on red5 0.9 version.

Below is my flex client code snippets. My red5 server work fine.

```
private var playStream:NetStream;

private function playRecord(event:MouseEvent):void{
  if(isPausing){
    playStream.togglePause();
  }else{
    playStream=getStream();
    playStream.bufferTime=15;
    playStream.play(streamName);
  }
}

private function pauseRecord(event:MouseEvent):void{
  playStream.togglePause();
}
```

I press `pause button` fine, but when i press `play button`, the audio always play form the begining.

Why? do i need to clean up NetStream Buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself.

```
playStream.maxPauseBufferTime=0;
```

Comment: [maxPauseBufferTime](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3_cn/langref/flash/net/NetStream.html#maxPauseBufferTime)